# Div Hover with Caption

Tags: jquery, css, html

I've been testing out Div hovering with CSS3 .. I've made a fiddle with all my coding, I have been using SASS to compile it (as it saves me writing lines and lines of code), but I've pasted that SASS here I've also been using compilers.

I'm not sure if jQuery is the way to go, if you hover over the **first** div from the top it shows the H4 element that comes from '.caption h4[rel="grid-title"]' and if you hover it from the bottom it shows the '.cross' element, I wanted to hover over the div itself and just have them apply themselves together.

```
/* ----- TYPOGRAPHY ----- */
%typography {
    font-family: $main-font;
    @include font-size(12);
    color: $main-fontcolour;
}

body {
    @extend %typography;
}
/* ----- PAGE ELEMENTS ----- */

.maincontainer {
    @include container;
}

section .centre {
    @include row;
}

.spacer {
    @include spacer;
}

// Extenders
%photoc {
    padding: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
// Wraps Around Photo
.photo-wrapper {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    @include relative;
    max-height: 320px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    @include columns (4);

            & .caption {
                background-color: rgba(177, 177, 177, 0);
                height: 0;
                min-height: 100%;
                min-width: 100%;
                @include notl;
                background-position: 50% -100%;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                @extend %photoc;
                @include transition(all, 300ms, ease-in-out);
                @include absolute;

                &:hover {
                    background-color: rgba(177, 177, 177, 0.3);
                    background-position: 50% 50%;
                    background-repeat: no-repeat;

                       img {
                           max-height: 100%;
                           @include transition(all, 300ms, ease-in-out);
                           }
                   }

        }
}

.caption .cross {
    @include absolute;
    @include notl;
    @include minper;
    background-image: url("http://suitabledesign.co/experiment/img/cross.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center -200%;
        &:hover {
            background-position: center center;
            @include transition (all, .25s, ease-in-out)
        }
}

.caption h4[rel="grid-title"] {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    @include font-size(14);
    @include absolute;
    @include notl;
    @include minper;
    @include translateY(-100px);

        &:hover {
            @include translateY(0px);
            @include transition (all, .25s, ease-in-out);
            top: 0;
    }
}
```

I'd appreciate any help I can get :)

**Edit:** Sorry I forgot the fiddle link.. http://jsfiddle.net/hounder/7gL8U/1/

Comment: What's the actual problem and where's the fiddle link?

Comment: and where is your fiddle ?

Comment: I edited and added my fiddle link, so sorry! It's [**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/hounder/7gL8U/1/) if you don't see it above. :)

Comment: what do u mean with pop in together?

Comment: Well.. Not pop in together but I have the class '.cross' and the class '.caption h4[rel="grid-title"]' both with a :hover element so I wanted to apply them both when the div gets hovered but at the moment only one or the other gets applied if you hover the first div from below or above h4 or the cross class get applied.

Comment: You should probably use `.photo-wrapper h4` instead of `h4[rel="grid-title"]` or apply a common class to them. I have been looking at your fiddle example in Chrome and I couldn't see the cross appear.. but also it seems like things are over complicated. I am not entirely sure what your trying to achieve from your examples so far.. but I would suggest you try hiding them instead and find a way to apply your animation just on the hover of the `div`

Comment: I'm trying to achive something like [this](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/OriginalHoverEffects/), not exactly the same but you get more of an idea.